# multiply list by list of ndarrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list

I want to multiply a list of numbers, by a ndarray, that is, each number in the list multiply by the first ndarray.

This is the list:

```
rad_glob = list(df_radiation_global['Radiacion Global'])
rad_glob
[840.6019233865843,
 838.5216723344233,
 848.0960914721192,
 868.2549621516736,
 856.395770948553,
 834.7011163700374,
 845.9590749318633,
 879.446257064898,
 650.7904290945771,
 814.4754071050489,
 736.1105621236436,
 736.0329394056781,
 873.7764268803811,
 870.1957716272296,
 904.985074880194,
 858.1357154671834,
 830.0583941643629,
 878.693702287297,
 848.669553553067,
 863.545204861961,
 825.3890093196567,
 842.5188280674437,
 865.3524589935482,
 833.5260196891436,
 276.4022647360663,
 915.9376255942822,
 864.3266555276591,
 770.448229104661,
 857.8907668737729,
 837.7897681015845,
 838.6796919844484,
 416.3444326406533,
 568.653862415028,
 884.4158558809625,
 825.3940207623805,
 798.0613412638792,
 863.0410218716003]
```

This is the list/df of ndarray

```
alb_lo = df_radiation_global['1 - Albedo']
alb_lo
0     [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.8528845...
1     [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
2     [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.8528845...
3     [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.8528845...
4     [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.8528845...
5     [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.8528845...
6     [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
7     [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
8     [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
9     [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
10    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.781219920000...
11    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.8528845...
12    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
13    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
14    [[nan, 0.79422526, 0.7942568400000001, 0.79905...
15    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
16    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
17    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
18    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.8528845...
19    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.8528845...
20    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
21    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
22    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.80179372, 0....
23    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.8528845...
24    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
25    [[nan, nan, 0.85725789, 0.85735359, 0.86033684...
26    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
27    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.8528845...
28    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.8528845...
29    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.84266864, nan, na...
30    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
31    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.8528845...
32    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.8528845...
33    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.8528845...
34    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.8528845...
35    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.8528845...
36    [[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
Name: 1 - Albedo, dtype: object
```

I want to multiply the first item in the list by the first ndarray. The nan values remain nan and just multiply the float numbers. I have tried with map, lambda function, iterations with for but I have not succeeded. The error that I get frequently is:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'. It can create a separate column with the new data, or simply create a list.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you reduce the size of your inputs to the _minimal_ number of rows and columns necessary to recreate your issue as well as include your expected output for the _provided_ input? See [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is the shape of `alb_lo`?

Comment: If you want in this question I have made it clearer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67449920/multiply-list-of-ndarrays-by-list

Comment: Are you sure rows are `ndarray`? Try `alb_lo.apply(type)` and check all rows are `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.

Answer (score 0):

all what you need to do is creaating new class from list class that can handle nan elements so you do not get exception
try:
var=[2,2,3]*"None"
except Exception  as yourexception:
print("this is your error .let me show you how to fix it ",yourexception)
class list_handle_none(list):

```
  def __mul__(self, other):
     if type(other)==type(3): 
      return list(self)*other
     elif type(other)==type("nan"):
      
    # raise TypeError("can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'")
      def handling_none(a):
          if "nan" in[a,other]:
              return "nan"
          else:
              return a*b
      return list(map(handling_none,list(self)))      
print(list_handle_none([1,2,3]))
print(list_handle_none([1,2,3])*"nan")
```